# Google Analytics filter with OR operator

Tags: google-analytics

I need to build a Google Analytics filter that includes all traffic from a selection of subdirectories, in my case all that start with customer and company.

You can see my configuration below, but the basic pattern is this:

```
/customer|/company
```

[image]

According to the Google help file one should be able to pipe together multiple patterns: 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034832?hl=en

But this clearly does not work. Any idea how to achive this?

**Update:**
I've tried @nyuen suggestion, but getting zero visitors like this. Do I have to switch to a custom filter?

[image]

**Solution:**
Customer filter with include was the solution.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that I immediately see:

1. Subdomain is not the same as subdirectory. A subdomain looks like `company.domain.com` or `customer.domain.com`. A subdirectory looks like `www.domain.com/customer` or `www.domain.com/company`.
2. If you are talking about subdomains, then you should use a regex match on a hostname of `(customer|company)\.domain\.com`. If you are talking about subdirectories, then you should use a regex match on a page path of `/(customer|company)/.*`.

Note that you can't use the `begins with` match type with a regular expression as you have in your example.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking about subdirectory. Sorry for this. I fixed the question. But it's still not working.

Comment: Sorry I'm not at my computer right now and I can't check, but try a Custom filter with your regex pattern.

Comment: Also note that to page paths (and subdirectories) are referred to, in custom filters, by "Request URI".

Comment: Request URI only contains the subdirectory? Not the whole URL? I'm still facing the issue that subdirectories like e.g. "/en/company/jobs" are also caught.

Comment: I saw your Solution above in your post, is everything OK now?

Comment: I've changed it now to ^/(customer|company)/.*